# C++ and box2d: userdata cast int to void*

Tags: c++, casting, box2d

i'm pretty new to box2d and i'm trying to use the userdata (of type void*) field in the b2body object to store an int value (an enum value, so i know the type of the object).

right now i'm doing something this:

```
int number = 1023;

void* data = (void*)(&number);

int rNumber = *(int*)data;
```

and i get the value correctly, but as i've been reading around casting to void* it's not portable or recommendable... is my code cross-platform? is it's behavior defined or implementation dependent?

Thanks!

Comment: The Windows API does this (and much, much worse) all the time. There's not much choice if you have no other way of storing it for later but a void pointer. You could do with putting in appropriate C++ casts, though (no cast for the first, and `static_cast` for the second).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually not casting `int` to `void*`, you cast `int*` to `void*`, which is totally different.

A pointer to any type can be stored in a `void*`, and be cast back again to the *same* type. That is guaranteed to work.

Casting to any other type is not portable, as the language standard doesn't say that different pointers have to be the same size, or work the same way. Just that `void*` has to be wide enough to contain them.

Answer (score 4):

Casting to `void *` is portable. It is not recommended because you are losing type safety. Anything can be put into a `void *` and anything can be gotten out. It makes it easier to shoot yourself in the foot. Otherwise `void *` is fine as long as you are careful and extra cautious.

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems with `void*` is that you need to know (keep track of) what type it originally was in order to cast it properly. If it originally was a `float` and you case it to an `int` the compiler would just take your word for it.

To avoid this you could create a wrapper for your data which contains the type, that way you will be able to always cast it to the right type.

Edit: you should also make a habit of using C++ casting style instead of C i.e. `reinterpret_cast`

Comment: what is the difference between those?

Answer (score 1):

void * is somehow a relic of the past (ISO C), but very convenient. You can use it safely as far as you are careful casting back and forward the type you want. Consider other alternatives like the c++ class system or overloading a function

anyways you will have better cast operators, some times there is no other way around (void*), some other times they are just too convenient.

It can lead to non portable code, not because of the casting system, but because some people are tempted to do non portable operations with them. The biggest problem lies in the fact that (void*) is a as big as a memory address, which in many platforms happens to be also the length of the platform integers.

However in some rare exceptions size(void*) != size(int)

If you try to do some type of operations/magic with them without casting back to the type you want, you might have problems. You might be surprised of how many times I have seen people wanting to store an integer into a void* pointer

Comment: The void pointer he's referring to in Box2D is for the convenience of the person using the framework. It allows you to get an object in the Box2D world point back to one of your own objects in your engine. There aren't any other practical ways of doing this without the void*.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, yes, it's safe to do.

To answer the question you didn't ask, that void pointer isn't meant for keeping an int in. Box2D has that pointer for you to point back to an Entity object in your game engine, so you can associate an Entity in your game to a b2Body in the physics simulation. It allows you to more easily program your entities interact with one another when one b2Body interacts with another.

So you shouldn't just be putting an enum in that void*. You should be pointing it directly to the game object represented by that b2body, which could have an enum in it.

Comment: I don't think it's fair to say userData is 'for' anything other than keeping some information that the developer wants to keep there.